# Transform.position not working unless setActive false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to using following codes to update transform position, from debug console, the position did change, however the object was not moving at all. If I set active false in advance, the object can move, but then scripts on its child object would be not working. This question blocked me for a long time, thanks any way.

```
void Update()
    {
        // gameObject.SetActive(false);
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(
            transform.position, 
            endPoint,
            50 * Time.deltaTime
        );

        // gameObject.SetActive(true);
        Debug.Log("position: " + transform.position);
    }
```

I also tried to change object parent, still can not make the object move.

Comment: sounds like maybe some animator or other component is overwriting the position?